# #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES and NO)

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

I change my hard of laptop so re install programs so I install the wamp server and when tried to access localhost from browser the page of username and password
so I enter the username root and leave password empty but I got this error :

> ## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

so I change the **config.inc.php** file by add password and change the allow to password from true to false

and this is the file:

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'h]C+{nqW$omNoTIkCwC$%z-LTcy%p6_j$|$Wv[mwngi~|e'; //What you want

//Checking Active DBMS Servers
$wampConf = @parse_ini_file('../../wampmanager.conf');
//Check if MySQL and MariaDB with MariaDB on default port
$mariaFirst = ($wampConf['SupportMySQL'] == 'on' && $wampConf['SupportMariaDB'] == 'on' && $wampConf['mariaPortUsed'] == $wampConf['mysqlDefaultPort']) ? true : false;
if($wampConf['SupportMySQL'] == 'on') {
/* Server: localhost [1] */
    $i++;
    if($mariaFirst) $i++;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'MySQL';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $wampConf['mysqlPortUsed'];
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';

    // Hidden databases in PhpMyAdmin left panel
    //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|sys)';

    // Allow connection without password
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
}
/* Server: localhost [2] */
if($wampConf['SupportMariaDB'] =='on') {
    $i++;
    if($mariaFirst) $i -= 2;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'MariaDB';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $wampConf['mariaPortUsed'];
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';

    // Hidden databases in PhpMyAdmin left panel
    //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|sys)';
    // Allow connection without password
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
}

// Suppress Warning about pmadb tables
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;

// To have PRIMARY & INDEX in table structure export
$cfg['Export']['sql_drop_table'] = true;
$cfg['Export']['sql_if_not_exists'] = true;

$cfg['MySQLManualBase'] = 'http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/';
/* End of servers configuration */

?>
```

and restart all services of wamp and open localhost again by enter root as username and root as password I got this error:

> ## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have tried all solutions on internet but can't find something work so what should I do to make it work

Comment: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` not much to it other then that, you have the wrong password. See [resetting roots password](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset).

Comment: There are nearly [2100 results for that search here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+access+denied+for+user+root). I find it pretty unlikely that you've tried all of them.

Comment: Oh and setting the password in the config will not fix this if the password you use is still not what is registered with MySQL. So the change you made to `config.inc.php` will change nothing and should be reverted

Comment: thanks for all of your response but nothing get work! I just uninstall the wamp then reinstall it then everything is work!